# What is the SQL Server timestamp equivalent in sqlce?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, sql-server-ce

I have some data with a timestamp in SQL Server, I would like to store that value in sqlce with out getting fancy to compare the two values.

What is the SQL Server timestamp equivalent in sqlce?

Comment: Please use "SQL Server" and not "ms sql". It makes it much easier for others to search.

Comment: Have you tried using `timestamp`? What happens?

Comment: `timestamp` is no good. I need to copy the existing timestamp from the sql server db to the sqlce db.

Comment: `timestamp` is a read only autogen....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the timestamp is a varbinary that auto generates. So to copy a time stamp you need a varbinary field.

Comment: Or cast it to a `BIGINT` since it is an 8 byte value.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is from [MS Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(SQL.80).aspx)

> timestamp is a  data type that exposes automatically generated binary numbers, which are guaranteed to be unique within a database. timestamp is used typically as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes.

This value makes no sense outside the database it was created in. Thus I don't see how it can be converted.

In a non Sybase/ SQL Server database I would use a version number or last updated column

Answer (score 0):

AS of Sql Compact 3.5, there is support for timestamps, per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417.aspx):

> SQL Server Compact implements the
>   timestamp (rowversion) data type. The
>   rowversion is a data type that exposes
>   automatically generated binary
>   numbers, which are guaranteed to be
>   unique in a database. It is used
>   typically as a mechanism for
>   version-stamping table rows.